# codeigniter delete 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added a delete link to the articles page, but when I click delete, in the URL its says ..........index.php/news/delet1 it picks out the id but comes up with a 404 error.

controller news.php

```
public function delete($id){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['title'] = 'Delete an item';

    if($this->news_model->delete_news($id)){
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);  
        $this->load->view('news/success');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

view.php

```
<p><a href="news/delete<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>">delete article</a></p>
```

news_model.php

```
public function delete_news($id){
    $this->db->where('id',$id)->delete('news');

    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

route

```
$route['news/delete/(:num)'] = 'news/delete/$1';
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link seems to be missing a forward slash to pass the ID. It should read:

`<p><a href="news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>">delete article</a></p>`

Comment: 2 minutes left will do once its over